# Ui-select ~ Use object key as value and object value as name

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jquery-select2, ui-select2

My users object looks as follows:

```
var users = {
    1: 'John Doe',
    7: 'Marry Match',
    13: 'Lindsay Lohan'
};
```

With 1, 7 and 13 being the user ID's and the names... Well, being the names.

How can I, in [ui-select](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-select) , populate my dropdown with my users?

I've tried the following

```
<ui-select ng-model="selectedUser" theme='select2' title="Choose a user">
    <ui-select-choices repeat="(id, name) in users | filter: $select.search">
        <span ng-bind="name"></span>
    </ui-select-choices>
</ui-select>
```

Answer (score 0):

The github has an [object-as-source-example](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-select/blob/master/examples/demo-object-as-source.html), and describes the repeat string as:

`person.key as (key, person) in peopleObj`

With that in mind maybe try:

```
<ui-select ng-model="selectedUser" theme='select2' title="Choose a user">
    <ui-select-choices repeat="name.id as (id, name) in users | filter $select.search">
        <span ng-bind="name"></span>
    </ui-select-choices>
</ui-select>
```

Comment: Thanks, but this doesn't work. The console fills up with transcluding errors and the list is empty.

Comment: Do you think you can provide a plunker of your source? Also I slightly edited the string for syntax reasons. Try `name.id as (id, name) in users | filter $select.search`

Comment: Hmm. Hate plunkr. Here you go: it doesn't even show the dropdown :) http://plnkr.co/edit/4i9zzYVr43C2M9xl0erW